# Broken Gnome panel after update

Tags: 11.10, gnome-panel

Like every single update on Ubuntu system,  
 
my graphical system is completely broken after updating to version 11.10 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/YIHfA.png] 
As shown in the image, the date is in the middle of the panel, 
There are many icons missing (network connection icon, skype) 
There's no right click menu when I try to right click on the panel 
and many programs don't have their menus (file,edit,view... those things).

How do I fix this? 
I have gnome-panel, I don't want Unity and I'd rather install windows 95 
before I switch to it.

Comment: just noticed that if I move my mouse to the left edge of the screen a Unity menu pops out, I do not wish to have it on top of all the things I wish to fix with my panel

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to revert to GNOME Classic?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic)

Comment: OK.. that just looks like Gnome Shell panel... on top of what is Unity..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have upgraded to Gnome 3 and your panel looks the way it is supposed to look. It is configurable, like the previous version was, but it doesn't have much configuration tools yet. You can use dconf-editor from [dconf-tools](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dconf-tools), but it isn't very user friendly.

It is incompatible with Gnome 2, so you won't have those applets, though some may have been ported. Gnome 2 has been deprecated (by Gnome, not by Ubuntu) and will not be available in any future versions. If you want to use Gnome 2, you should probably use 10.04 or maybe 11.04. 10.04 is supported a little longer, though.